# Using Foursquare's API to get venues into an NSArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, foursquare

I'm trying to save venues into a `NSArray`. Venue is an array in an `NSDictionary` Response. I would like an `NSArray` with all the venues so I can populate a table.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=dog&limit=10"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSDictionary *responseData = [JSON objectForKey:@"response"];
    self.venues = responseData[@"venues"];

    [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
}];
[operation start];
```

Four squares partial

```
response: {
    venues: [{
        id: "4ea2c02193ad755e37150c15"
        name: "The Grey Dog"
        contact: {
            phone: "+12129661060"
            formattedPhone: "+1 212-966-1060"
        }
        location: {
            address: "244 Mulberry St"
            crossStreet: "btwn Spring & Prince St"
            lat: 40.723096
            lng: -73.995774
            distance: 2595
            postalCode: "10012"
            city: "New York"
            state: "NY"
            country: "United States"
            cc: "US"
        }
```

[Link to Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a new array to hold all the Venues.

First create a global `NSDictionary` like:

```
NSDictionary* venuesDict;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* venuesDict;
```

and synthesise it. You can then assign it in you code above like so:

```
venuesDict = [[JSON objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"venues"];
NSLog(@"%@", venuesDict); //everything should work up to here!
```

---

Presuming the NSLog prints the output as you posted in you question (but with venues as the first object), you can populate a table like this:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[venuesDict objectForKey:@"venues"] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[venuesDict objectForKey@"venues"] objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: self.venuesDict = [JSON objectForKey:@"venues"]; it gets this output 2013-02-20 15:39:22.595 GeoPhotos[70995:11303] (null). If I put response instead of venues then it gets all the responses. Venues are inside of responses and I need to access venue.

Comment: Oops, I made an error - see updated answer with `venuesDict = [[JSON objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"venues"];`

Comment: I'm getting null output for the NSlog.

Comment: I'm still not getting any value for the NSlog. Nothing is being saved in venues.

Comment: Hmm, what if you just do `NSLog(@"%@", [[JSON objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"venues"]);`

Comment: Strange. Im getting all the data from the foursquare api except for venues. Will have to think about this. I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Did you include your `client_id` and `client_secret` in the url like so: `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=dog&limit=10&client_secret=INPUT&client_id=INPUT`

Comment: Ok it was because I didn't have the correct url. The correct url is the url i gave include v=20130220 which is todays date. ITs working now.

Comment: PLease just edit your code to incude the character ":" after the @ symbol in the objectkey. Thank you so much for the help.